# i made a large scene and when i start animating it, boom all vanished

Tags: animation

i  made characters in one file of blender and named it *****(secret). 
i made a treehouse scene in another blender file. then i opened character's file and clicked appear which is in top right option "file". and linked only the scene and not lightnings and camera.

i finished the very called frame work and pressed that animation button which lead me to a empty screen with the only things i created while doing the frame work. which was some text and a backgroud (i imported the image on plane).

i am in a great trouble i can't do that all agin its too long. please help me here .please[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is animation playing nice in solid shading mode.

Comment: Can you send an .blend file please